# jquery+php captcha plugin

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

I've searched through the net for various captcha, but couldn't found anything which suit my needs.

What I basically want is as follows:

1. I have a form with a file input box so user could upload file
   through the form been shown. I now need to add a captcha to
   eradicate the spam.

But when a user enters invalid code in the captcha text box I want to have all the fields filled in with the values entered by the user.So that if user enters invalid code he would just need to enter the code again and no need to fill up the form.I can show all the field values currently except the file input box.

What is happening with me is I have to again upload the same file if I enter a wrong code in the captcha box ... this is little frustrating.

So can anyone let me know if there is any plugin which does this sort of mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I am using recaptcha and it's already support ajax

you can check demo at

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax

How to use

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

check Ajax API

Comment: ya I had checked this first ... but the letters are not clear to even me .I can understand the security reasons behind this ... so any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jquery4u.com/security/10-jquery-captcha-plugins/

Ah, google saves the day again.

Comment: eventually i had checked this site too and tried a few of those but it didn't solved my issue ... i.e I don't want to ask the user to upload his file again when he enters a wrong code in the captcha field